# Performance tips for slow running SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, explain

I have query I'm trying to performance tune it's currently running slow, around 30 minutes, which isn't great as I'm trying to put this query into an Oracle form.

Is there any way on making the below query quicker. What should I be looking at or what should I try to improve the performance of this query.

The size of the tables are as follows.

- third_parties has 2692 rows.
- broadcasters has 2478 rows.
- productions has 244,326,797 rows.
- usage_headers has 852,578,899 rows

I guess below query might run quicker if executed in the above order from top to bottom (from small table to the biggest).

```
 select broadcaster_tp.THIRD_PARTY_SURR_ID
       ,broadcaster_tp.THIRD_PARTY_GROUP_ID
       ,broadcaster_tp.THIRD_PARTY_ROOT_ID
       ,broadcaster_tp.SUPPLIER_NAME
       ,broadcaster_tp.STATION_ID
       ,broadcaster_tp.BROADCASTER_NAME
       ,usage_headers.bro_broadcast_by_tp_surr_id
       ,usage_headers.production_number
       ,usage_headers.prod_exploitation_cre_surr_id
       ,productions.production_source
       ,productions.cre_surr_id
       ,productions.prod_series_cre_surr_id
       ,usage_headers.right_type
       ,usage_headers.dn_uls_usage_status
    from ( select  third_party.surr_id as THIRD_PARTY_SURR_ID, 
                   third_party.supplier_group_id as THIRD_PARTY_GROUP_ID,
                   third_party.dn_root_tp_surr_id as THIRD_PARTY_ROOT_ID,
                   third_party.supplier_name as SUPPLIER_NAME,
                   broadcasters.station_id as STATION_ID,
                   broadcasters.dn_tp_name as BROADCASTER_NAME
            from  (SELECT third_parties.surr_id, 
                          third_parties.name as supplier_name,
                          third_parties.tp_surr_id as supplier_group_id, 
                          third_parties.dn_root_tp_surr_id 
                   FROM third_parties
                   CONNECT BY PRIOR third_parties.surr_id =          third_parties.tp_surr_id
                   START WITH third_parties.surr_id IN (4251,4247,4237,4034,10157)) third_party   -- just a selected group of third party groups to be used        
                   JOIN broadcasters                  ON (third_party.surr_id     = broadcasters.tp_surr_id)) broadcaster_tp
        , usage_headers
        , productions
   WHERE usage_headers.bro_broadcast_by_tp_surr_id = broadcaster_tp.THIRD_PARTY_SURR_ID
   AND usage_headers.prod_exploitation_cre_surr_id = productions.cre_surr_id 
   AND usage_headers.prod_exploitation_cre_surr_id IS NOT NULL
   AND usage_headers.right_type = 'M'            
   AND usage_headers.udg_surr_id               IS NOT NULL                
   AND usage_headers.dn_uls_usage_status       NOT IN ('9', '11')         -- not deleted or distributed
   AND productions.production_source <> 'AP'
   AND broadcaster_tp.THIRD_PARTY_SURR_ID = 4035 -- users to pick the third party id from screen
   AND broadcaster_tp.STATION_ID = 'BTWONE'   -- users to pick the station id from screen
   AND usage_headers.bro_broadcast_by_tp_surr_id = 4035; -- users to pick broadcaster from screen
```

The indexes and explain plan are below.

```
THIRD_PARTIES
INFO,       INDEX_NAME,                     UNIQUE, LOGGING,    DEGREE, COLUMN_NAME,                    ORDER   
PLAIN,      TP_PK,                          Y,      NO,         1,      SURR_ID,                        Asc 
PLAIN,      TP_TP_FK_I,                     N,      NO,         1,      TP_SURR_ID,                     Asc 
FUNCTION,   TP_UK1,                         Y,      NO,         1,      UPPER("NAME"),                  Asc 

BROADCASTERS
INFO,       INDEX_NAME,                     UNIQUE, LOGGING,    DEGREE, COLUMN_NAME,                    ORDER       
PLAIN,      BRO_DOM_FK_I,                   N,      YES,        1,      DOM_SURR_ID,                    Asc     
PLAIN,      BRO_ELT_FK_I,                   N,      YES,        1,      ELT_CODE,                       Asc     
PLAIN,      BRO_PK,                         Y,      YES,        1,      TP_SURR_ID,                     Asc     
PLAIN,      BRO_TP_ROLLUP_FK_I,             N,      YES,        1,      TP_ROLLUP_SURR_ID,              Asc     
PLAIN,      BRO_UK1,                        Y,      YES,        1,      STATION_ID,                     Asc     


USAGE_HEADERS
INFO,       INDEX_NAME,                     UNIQUE, LOGGING,    DEGREE, COLUMN_NAME,                    ORDER   
PLAIN,      UDG_ORIGINAL_SURR_ID_FK_I,      N,      YES,        1,      UDG_ORIGINAL_SURR_ID,           Asc     
PLAIN,      UH_BRO_BROADCAST_BY_FK_I,       N,      YES,        1,      BRO_BROADCAST_BY_TP_SURR_ID,    Asc     
PLAIN,      UH_BRO_ORIG_BROADCAST_BY_FK_I,  N,      YES,        1,      BRO_ORIG_BRO_BY_TP_SURR_ID,     Asc     
PLAIN,      UH_ELT_FK_I,                    N,      YES,        1,      ELT_CODE,                       Asc     
PLAIN,      UH_FL_FK_I,                     N,      YES,        1,      FL_SURR_ID,                     Asc     
PLAIN,      UH_I1,                          N,      YES,        1,      PERFORMANCE_DATE,               Asc     
                                                                        BRO_BROADCAST_BY_TP_SURR_ID
PLAIN,      UH_PK,                          Y,      YES,        1,      SURR_ID,                        Asc     
PLAIN,      UH_PN_I,                        N,      YES,        1,      PRODUCTION_NUMBER, 
                                                                        PROGRAMME_NAME
PLAIN,      UH_PP_FK_I,                     N,      YES,        1,      PP_SURR_ID,                     Asc     
PLAIN,      UH_PROD_EXPLOITATION_FK_I,      N,      YES,        1,      PROD_EXPLOITATION_CRE_SURR_ID,  Asc     
PLAIN,      UH_UDG_FK_I,                    N,      YES,        1,      UDG_SURR_ID,                    Asc     
PLAIN,      UH_UK1,                         Y,      YES,        1,      PROD_RECEIVED_WITH_CRE_SURR_ID, Asc     

PRODUCTIONS
INFO,       INDEX_NAME,                     UNIQUE, LOGGING,    DEGREE, COLUMN_NAME,                    ORDER
PLAIN,      PROD_DOM_INT_IND_I,             N,      YES,        1,      DOMESTIC_INTERNATIONAL_IND,     Asc
PLAIN,      PROD_ELT_FK,                    N,      YES,        1,      ELT_CODE,                       Asc
PLAIN,      PROD_I2,                        N,      YES,        1,      EPISODE_NUMBER,                 Asc
PLAIN,      PROD_I3,                        N,      YES,        1,      SUPPLIER_RELEASE_ID,            Asc
PLAIN,      PROD_PK,                        Y,      YES,        1,      CRE_SURR_ID,                    Asc
FUNCTION,   PROD_PK_CHAR,                   Y,      YES,        1,      CRE_SURR_ID_CHAR,               Asc
PLAIN,      PROD_PROD_DUPLICATE_FK_I,       N,      YES,        1,      PROD_DUPLICATE_CRE_SURR_ID,     Asc
PLAIN,      PROD_PROD_MASTER_FK_I,          N,      YES,        1,      PROD_MASTER_CRE_SURR_ID,        Asc
FUNCTION,   PROD_PROD_SERIES_FK_CHAR,       N,      YES,        1,      PROD_SERIES_CRE_SURR_ID_CHAR,   Asc
PLAIN,      PROD_PROD_SERIES_FK_I,          N,      YES,        1,      PROD_SERIES_CRE_SURR_ID,        Asc
PLAIN,      PROD_SLH_SET_LIST_ID_I,         N,      YES,        1,      SLH_SET_LIST_ID,                Asc






    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |   Id  | Operation                          | Name                     | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                   |                          |     7 |   924 |  6995   (1)| 00:01:24 |
    |   1 |  NESTED LOOPS                      |                          |       |       |            |          |
    |   2 |   NESTED LOOPS                     |                          |     7 |   924 |  6995   (1)| 00:01:24 |
    |   3 |    NESTED LOOPS                    |                          |    13 |  1573 |  6956   (1)| 00:01:24 |
    |   4 |     NESTED LOOPS                   |                          |    12 |  1248 |     6   (0)| 00:00:01 |
    |*  5 |      TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID   | BROADCASTERS             |     1 |    33 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
    |*  6 |       INDEX UNIQUE SCAN            | BRO_PK                   |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
    |*  7 |      VIEW                          |                          |    12 |   852 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
    |*  8 |       CONNECT BY WITH FILTERING    |                          |       |       |            |          |
    |   9 |        INLIST ITERATOR             |                          |       |       |            |          |
    |  10 |         TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| THIRD_PARTIES            |     5 |   180 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
    |* 11 |          INDEX UNIQUE SCAN         | TP_PK                    |     5 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
    |  12 |        NESTED LOOPS                |                          |       |       |            |          |
    |  13 |         CONNECT BY PUMP            |                          |       |       |            |          |
    |  14 |         TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| THIRD_PARTIES            |    12 |   432 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
    |* 15 |          INDEX RANGE SCAN          | TP_TP_FK_I               |    12 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
    |* 16 |     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID    | USAGE_HEADERS            |     1 |    17 |   595   (1)| 00:00:08 |
    |* 17 |      INDEX RANGE SCAN              | UH_BRO_BROADCAST_BY_FK_I |   218 |       |   529   (1)| 00:00:07 |
    |* 18 |    INDEX UNIQUE SCAN               | PROD_PK                  |     1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
    |* 19 |   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID      | PRODUCTIONS              |     1 |    11 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


   Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
   ---------------------------------------------------

   5 - filter("BROADCASTERS"."STATION_ID"='BTWONE')
   6 - access("BROADCASTERS"."TP_SURR_ID"=4035)
   7 - filter("THIRD_PARTY"."SURR_ID"=4035)
   8 - access("THIRD_PARTIES"."TP_SURR_ID"=PRIOR "THIRD_PARTIES"."SURR_ID")
   11 - access("THIRD_PARTIES"."SURR_ID"=4034 OR "THIRD_PARTIES"."SURR_ID"=4237 OR 
              "THIRD_PARTIES"."SURR_ID"=4247 OR "THIRD_PARTIES"."SURR_ID"=4251 OR "THIRD_PARTIES"."SURR_ID"=10157)
   15 - access("THIRD_PARTIES"."TP_SURR_ID"=PRIOR "THIRD_PARTIES"."SURR_ID")
   16 - filter("USAGE_HEADERS"."PROD_EXPLOITATION_CRE_SURR_ID" IS NOT NULL AND 
              "USAGE_HEADERS"."UDG_SURR_ID" IS NOT NULL AND "USAGE_HEADERS"."RIGHT_TYPE"='M' AND 
              "USAGE_HEADERS"."DN_ULS_USAGE_STATUS"<>'9' AND "USAGE_HEADERS"."DN_ULS_USAGE_STATUS"<>'11')
   17 - access("USAGE_HEADERS"."BRO_BROADCAST_BY_TP_SURR_ID"=4035)
       filter("USAGE_HEADERS"."BRO_BROADCAST_BY_TP_SURR_ID"="THIRD_PARTY"."SURR_ID")
   18 - access("USAGE_HEADERS"."PROD_EXPLOITATION_CRE_SURR_ID"="PRODUCTIONS"."CRE_SURR_ID")
   19 - filter("PRODUCTIONS"."PRODUCTION_SOURCE"<>'AP')
```

Comment: Not related to performance, but you should always use explicit join syntax (`join ... on ...`)

Comment: Sorry HoneyBadger, I've been doing ORACLE for 20 years and I guess I've just picked up bad habits

Comment: how many rows has the final resultset? and the connect by-s?

Comment: The plan seems to be ok. What is the selectivity of UH_BRO_BROADCAST_BY_FK_I index?

Comment: What do you mean Petr Pribyl with selectivity?

Comment: I mean how many distinct values are in UH_BRO_BROADCAST_BY_FK index columns compared to all table rows. According to table volumes zou select about 300 000 usage_headers per broadcaster. It can be slower. Try select from usage_headers joined only with production for usage_headers.bro_broadcast_by_tp_surr_id = 4035. Is this quick?

Comment: 3817 rows are brought back for a usage_headers.bro_broadcast_by_tp_surr_id = 4035  - Petr Priby

Comment: I would expect this number in Rows column of your plan in operation 17. Do you have statisticts computed? The plan looks like using rule based optimization.